# how can i make this query in Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, postgresql, elasticsearch

Postgresql query like this :

`select * from equipment where production_day < now() + interval '-1 years' * endurance_period + interval '1 month'`

endurance_period is column name in table.
How can I convert this query to Query DSL(JSON) in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 0):

you can do date time manipulations for fields on date fields

Small example of using date math/function manipulations inside the range filter

```
{
    "range" : {
        "date" : {
            "gte" : "now-1d/d",
            "lt" :  "now/d"
        }
    }
}
```

so your query may look more or less like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "range": {
                            "created_at": {
                                "lte": "now-1*3d/d"
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can extend the gte equation to match your search filter criteria.

[Date Function elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)

Comment: What does the `*` operator do?

Comment: it should multiply. i tried few dummy queries before posting here, was working just fine for me.